# Angular GET: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, google-chrome

I am aware that there is a plenty of topics with similar problems. However none of them helped me to solve problem which I am struggling with.

Using Angular and restangular (https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) I want to make a GET request to the server. But when I try to connect like this:

```
Restangular.one('data').get()
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
},
function(){
    console.log('error');
});
```

I receive this error:

```
OPTIONS [domain address]  401 ()
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [domain address] Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

I have read little bit about CORS and I tried to change my headers like this:

```
 app.config(function($httpProvider){

 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};

 });
```

Also I download Chrome extension but none of those things succeed. I am sure that authentication is correct since I've tested it with curl and postman. This bug seems to be independent from content of the request of my header. How can I fix it?

Comment: The issue is how the server is responding to the CORS pre-flight (`OPTIONS` request). You'll want to post your server code. You also may need to add `withCredentials` to your AJAX request if it's missing cookies that are your issue.

Comment: What language is your API written in? If you hosting your API locally, you need to enable CORS. 

if its written in C# as WebAPI 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: hafridi: no it is not written in C# language

Comment: Either way you need to enable cors on your api when running it locally

Comment: The browser is blocking the response because it violates [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). To get the browser to relax SOP, the server needs to respond with CORS headers to the pre-flight request. For more information, see [MDN HTTP Reference - HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).